# Fourier transform of a 2-D Gaussian on a ring

Tags: fourier-analysis

I need some help obtaining the 2-D Fourier transform of the following function:

$$f(r)=e^{-\frac{-2(r-a)^{2}}{w^{2}}}$$

Where $r$ is the polar radius, $a$ and $w$ are positive. So this describes a radially symmetric Gaussian on a ring of radius $a$. I tried solving it for $a=0$ and applying a simple translation, but this doesn't seem to work as it does in the 1-D case, since this is really a Hankel transform due to the radial symmetry. The definition of a (edit: 1-D) Fourier transform which I am using is:

$$\hat{f}(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\ e^{-ixk}\, dx$$

Does anyone have any idea how to approach this?

Edit: Just to confirm, the integral I need seems to be $$\int_{0}^{\infty}f(r)\, J_{0}(kr)rdr$$

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: It has to do with a ring-shaped SQUID (superconducting quantum interference device). $f$ is related to finding the magnetic flux through the SQUID.

Comment: Do you think you can evaluate that integral?

Answer (score 1):

Please check page 7.7.3 of ERDELYI_Higher Transcendental Functions_Volume 2.

The integral closest to the one that you need is:

[image]

Comment: If $a=0$ in his function then he can use this result.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\hat{f}(k_x,k_y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\, dx \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\, dyf(x,y)\ e^{-ixk_x-iyk_y}$$

$$\hat{f}(k,\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\, rdr\int_{0}^{2\pi}\, d\phi f(r)\ e^{-ir k \cos(\phi-\alpha)} $$

Comment: Please see my edit --- I have gotten that far but I am stuck on the radial integral.